# checking if a meta description is present using selenium IDE?

Tags: html, css, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

Currently, I'm using the following Command & Target within Selenium IDE to verify the exact text of a meta description

```
 verifyelementpresent :    //meta[@name='description' and @content='description here']
```

I would like to check if the meta description is between 145 and 165 characters to see if it exists. that way when the description changes, the test will only fail if the description is under 145 lines or over 165(which a meta description cant be anyway)

can anyone assist me in writing this expression?  assuming some sort of variable is necessary under content to check length of..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute this javascript with selenium:

```
document.evaluate("/html/head/meta[@name='description']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.content.length >= 144 
&& document.evaluate("/html/head/meta[@name='description']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.content.length <= 166;
```

> You need to subtract 1 from the initial value and add 1 at the end value because the content is returned with ""

It returns true or false.

Or you can evaluate the meta description content and apply validations inside your app, like

```
document.evaluate("/html/head/meta[@name='description']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.content
```

Comment: thanks. it appears to work for a bit, then starts failing random pages that do indeed have their meta descriptions filled.  not sure why, but ive come a little further because of your post. thanks.  edit: actually, the script works fine. had a couple under 144 char.  thanks! thumbs up

Comment: @TestWater You can get only the content with `document.evaluate("/html/head/meta[@name='description']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.content` and apply your validations inside your app... And if it worked for you, please check as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I consider a better, more selenese code (useable/readable):

```
<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>//meta[@name=&quot;description&quot;]@content</td>
    <td>meta_val</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['meta_val'].length &gt; 145 &amp;&amp; storedVars['meta_val'].length&lt;165;</td>
    <td>true</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['meta_val'].length;</td>
    <td>meta_length</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${meta_length}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```